# Responsive web: SVG visualization?

Tags: javascript, svg, media-queries, responsive-design, modernizr

I am building an interactive SVG visualization (see image) and would like to provide:

**1) Adaptation to smaller screen sizes (media queries?)**

**2) A decent fallback when JavaScript is disabled (Modernizr?)**

***Regarding 1:***

Do you think it is better to work with fixed/discrete pixel widths or should I just have the SVG block adapt to the available width?

Do I need a window resize listener to dynamically update the layout or is that overkill when using media queries?

***Regarding 2:***

Keeping the design responsive, what would be a good way of replacing the SVG visualization with static images?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, couldn't you just use media queries for 1 and that way issue 2 no longer becomes an issue?

Comment: Bitmap images and server work could be used as a catchall if Javascript is not available. After all your graph data is in a database or flat file?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think it is better to work with fixed/discrete pixel widths or should I just have the SVG block adapt to the available width?

Scaling is the primary strength of vector graphics, so why not?

> Do I need a window resize listener to dynamically update the layout or is that overkill when using media queries?

No

> Keeping the design responsive, what would be a good way of replacing the SVG visualization with static images?

Convert the [JSON data source to XML](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/response.html), generate the [SVG using XSLT](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/09/08/tree.html) on the server, then send the static SVG to the client